# AWS load balancer sticky session cookie security

Tags: amazon-web-services, session-cookies, amazon-elb

I have an application which uses AWS load balancer. The application shows that the  AWSALB Cookie is not marked with the "secure" attribute.[Attached image shows the cookies used in the application where AWSALB cookie marked without secure attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxzBI.png)

Comment: It is expected - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html - "You can't set the secure flag or HttpOnly flag on your duration-based session stickiness cookies. However, these cookies contain no sensitive data."